# Put all the background color in this XML - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

this is the first part of my xml, it is a cardview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cvPhase"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grayBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"

    >
```

And my imageView

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_top"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_white"
   />
```

the result is this

[image]

I would like the entire background to be seen in gray and not just the bottom, the image is still on top of the color, how would I make the image also colored?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your cardview height is wrap content and matching your imageview height you should give height for your cardview

Answer (score 0):

Make your Cardview height as "match_parent".

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cvPhase"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grayBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    />
```